# why my javascript function inside prototype return true or false

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a module. What I am doing is when I create a new instance of object `func` function inside module is automatically gets called inside constructor. `func()` returns true if b is true or false if not. However, it returns the object i.e. `Module`. **Why?**

```
var Module = function () { this.func() };

Module.prototype = function () {
    var b = true;

    func = function() {
        if (b) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };

    return {
        func: func
    }
}();

console.log(new Module());
```

When I stop calling `anyMobile()` function inside constructor and make new instance of `IsMobile` and then call `anyMobile()` like below, then it does return true or false.

```
var m = new Module();
m.func(); //Works
```

Comment: Not quite understand, how you call IsMobile in first case?

Comment: You did some strange things to the working original found [here](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2011/11/detecting-mobile-devices-with-javascript/), you might want to replace your code

Answer (score 0):

because of this -

```
return {
        func: func
    }
```

anyMobile to be publicly accessed is an `object` which holds a function.

if you were to do `func: func()` instead (This would now be a function call which will return a boolean value), it should work!

Check out the concepts beautifully explained [here](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#1)

Answer (score 0):

The first line in your sample is a declaring a function that acts as a constructor.

```
var IsMobile = function () { this.anyMobile() };
```

When you call new IsMobile()

1. a new object OBJ is created with IsMobile.prototype as it's proto object (to inherit the properties defined on IsMobile.prototype)
2. the constructor function IsMobile is called with this bound to OBJ
3. if the constructor returns an object, it is returned, otherwise OBJ is returned

In your case, the anyMobile() method gets called in the constructor code, but the return value is ignored.

I would recommend you alter your code to not create a new IsMobile object each time, like this:

```
IsMobile = function () {
    var android = function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
    },

    blackBerry = function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
    },

    iOS = function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i);
    },

    windows = function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
    },

    anyMobile = function() {
        if (android() || blackBerry() || iOS() || windows()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };

    return anyMobile;
}();

console.log(IsMobile());
```

Also, since the navigator object doesn't change, you could simply retain the returned value and not compute it each time.

```
IsMobile = function () {
    var android = function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
    },

    blackBerry = function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
    },

    iOS = function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i);
    },

    windows = function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
    },

    anyMobile = function() {
        if (android() || blackBerry() || iOS() || windows()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };

    return anyMobile();
}();

console.log(IsMobile);
```